# How to do "ntile() over (partition by ) in MYSQL"

Tags: mysql

Actually i need to do `ntile(x) over(partition by )` query in mysql but I didn't get any good link or material for doing this.

So please help me how to do `ntile` function over `partition by`.

Answer (score 1):

`NTILE` is a window function that, AFAIK, is unavailable in MySQL. You can probably do something similar with `GROUP_CONCAT`. See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40203).

Comment: I guess `NTILE` *function* is [now available](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_ntile) [`MySQL 8.0`]